# How do you turn an array into a hash by assigning random values from another array?

Tags: ruby

I have an array, `names`, containing 12 names.

I have another array, `weights`, containing 12 numbers.

I want to create a hash where the keys are names, and the values weights.

The weight figures are predetermined (they should always be, for example, 200, 150, and 180), but they should be assigned to random names each time the program is run.

For example, if I use the arrays `names = ['homer', 'marge', 'maggie']` and `weights = [265, 140, 10]`, I could run the program and get `{homer: 140, marge: 265, maggie: 10}`, then rerun it and get `{homer: 10, marge: 140, maggie: 265}`.

What is the sensible way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The other answer almost got it, but it didn't shuffle the `weights` array first, so it would always return the same hash.

However, this will work as expected:

```
names.zip(weights.shuffle).to_h
```

Comment: Minor, we could use the Hash[] method instead of `to_h`.

`Hash[names.zip(weights.shuffle)]`

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland, I copied the other answer and just added the ``.shuffle`` to it and it worked, so I didn't realize that it was redundant.